# Is a generic type defined in inner class / interface bound to the outer class generic type definition?

Tags: java, generics

In this code:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Enum<T>> {

    public static interface MyInt<T> {

    }

    // ...

}
```

Is the type `T` in `MyInt<T>` the same as `T` in `MyClass<T extends Enum<T>>`? Or does that define a new generic type, so that moving that interface to a separate file won't change anything?

*After thinking a bit more about it, I guess the two types are independent, since I can always instantiate an object based on the interface (with* `new MyInt<Integer>() { ... }`*) without any reference to the outer class; but I'm anyway asking it to gather comments and thoughts.*

Comment: It is the new generic type as nested (`static`) classes are almost the same as same-package ordinary classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll have to look it up in the JLS but from what I remember inner interfaces are always static, i.e. the `static` keyword is not needed. Thus `MyInt` is completely independent from `MyClass` except that `MyClass` acts as a namespace for `MyInt`.

If `MyInt` were a non-static inner class the type parameter of `MyInt` would hide/redefine the type parameter of `MyClass`, since `MyInt` would then not be independent from `MyClass`.

From the [JLS §8.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1):

> A member interface is implicitly static

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both `T's` are independent of each other. Why?. Well because *generics* is defined at class level. A static inner class / interface cannot access the *type* defined by its enclosing class whereas a inner class (non-static class) can.

Example :

```
public class Test<T> {
public void printMe(T t) {
    System.out.println("Test");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

}

public static interface MyInt<E> {
    public void someMethod(T t);

    // compilation error - What is 'T'? .
    public void someOtherMethod(S s);

    // compilation error - What is 'S'? .
    public void methodDoesntCompile(E e);

}

class AnotherTest<S> {
    public void someMethod(T t) {
        // T is valid. Referred from parent class
        System.out.println("someMethod");
    }

    public void someOtherMethod(S s) {
        System.out.println("someMethod");
    }

    public void methodDoesntCompile(E e) {
        // compilation error - What is 'E'? .
        System.out.println("someMethod");
    }

}

static class StaticAnotherTest<Q> {
    public void someMethod(T t) {
        // compilation error - What is 'T'? .
        System.out.println("someMethod");
    }

    public void someOtherMethod(Q q) {

        System.out.println("someMethod");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What about a method `<P> methodWithNonClassGenericType( P param )`?

Comment: @Thomas - It is possible to define those. What about it?

Comment: I just wanted to say the generics are not always defined at a class level :)

Comment: @Thomas - Oh, I agree :)